# Magento javascript error after changing the base URL and flushing the cache

Tags: javascript, magento

I am getting an error after changing the site base URL from the admin panel.

Afterwards I flushed the cache and session directory.

The product is not loading properly on the home page.

Below is a screenshot of what I see.

[image: Developer tools open display javascript errors]

[This](http://ezdaam.com/prelaunch/) is the website.

Comment: Looks like you need to update the paths to your scripts now you've changed the base URL.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have Change from Admin,Currently path is same,is this issue of path?